# Why is my DataGrid with a ObservableCollection<T> apparently not refreshing when I add or remove items from the collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm having a problem with a DataGrid and its underlying ObservableCollection.  I want to add and remove rows programmatically from the collection and have the results appear in the DataGrid.  While I expect that this will automagically happen for me, it doesn't.  I've found that if I sort the data afterwards, that the rows will appear as I want them.  Here's what I do:

1. DataGrid's ItemsSource is set to my ObservableCollection<T>.
2. User clicks button that fires an ICommand that removes rows with a value of X.
3. What the user sees looks exactly the same: no rows are removed.
4. User clicks column header to sort the DataGrid.  Now the rows are removed.

What's going on here?  The rows that I want removed, stay until I sort the columns.  I found out something else as well.  If I refresh the DataGrid.Items, the rows are removed.  That code is simply:

```
this.dg.Items.Refresh();  //"dg" is my DataGrid
```

While this is not very MVVM, it works.

Comment: You're binding *directly* to an observable collection, yes?  You're not tacking on any Linq operators or anything like that?

Comment: Post the xaml and viewmodel code which are relevant to what you're talking about.

Comment: Are you firing you PropertyChanged event on your `ObersvableCollections` `CollectionChanged` event?

Comment: @MikeStrobel, that was it.  I overlooked how I was doing the binding.  I'd mark your comment as the answer if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're binding *directly* to your `ObservableCollection`, e.g., you are not tacking on any Linq operators, wrapping it in a collection view/proxy, etc.  Any transformation/wrapper on your collection that does not forward collection change events will prevent the grid from being notified of changes.